# How to change value of object using a direction var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

the code below is an object from database

```
{
  "id_": "1",
  "name": "Enemy x",
  "image": "image.png",
  "stats": {
    "level": 1,
    "attack": 5,
    "defense": 0
  }
}
```

And need edit attack or defense, but with a "pointer" saved in a constant, All this in a dynamic way since the value to edit could be in a third or fourth level of the object. for example:

```
const edit = 'stats/attack';
// const edit = 'stats/other/example'; <- example
```

I have some ideas but I don't know if exist best practices for this, or how to look for it on the internet since I can't find anything like it.

Comment: `stats.attack`?

Comment: How to make it dynamic if I have the location in a const? `const location = "stats.attack"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a reduce:

```js
const data = 
  { id_   : '1'
  , name  : 'Enemy x'
  , image : 'image.png'
  , stats: 
    { level   : 1
    , attack  : 5
    , defense : 0
  } }

function getVal( obj, key )
  {
  return key.split('/').reduce((o,v)=>o[v],obj)
  }
  
  
console.log('--> ', getVal( data, 'stats/attack' ))
```

In case of a wrong path:

```js
const data = 
  { id_   : '1'
  , name  : 'Enemy x'
  , image : 'image.png'
  , stats: 
    { level   : 1
    , attack  : 5
    , defense : 0
  } }

const getVal = ( obj, path ) =>
  path.split('/').reduce((o,v)=> o?.[v] ,obj) // better than `o[v] ?? 'error!`'
 
console.log('1-->', getVal( data, 'stats/attack' )) // --> 5    
console.log('2-->', getVal( data, 'stats/xxx' ))   //  --> undefined
console.log('3-->', getVal( data, 'zzz/xxx' ))    //   --> undefined
console.log('4-->', getVal( data, '' ))          //    --> undefined


//  thanks to pilchard comment
console.log('5-->', getVal( data, 'stats/xxx/1' )) //  --> undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

> PO :  if I want to change it to 10. I will test to see if I can do it with this method

maybe that ?
usage 1 : get the value

```
let val = onElm( data, 'stats/attack' )
```

usage 2 : change the value (to 10)

```
let val = onElm( data, 'stats/attack', 10 )
```

Demo;

```js
const data = 
  { id_   : '1'
  , name  : 'Enemy x'
  , image : 'image.png'
  , stats: 
    { level   : 1
    , attack  : 5
    , defense : 0
  } }

const onElm = ( obj, path, newVal=null ) =>
  path.split('/').reduce((o,p,i,{length:n}) =>
    (++i<n) ? o[p] : newVal ? o[p] = newVal : o[p], obj)
 

console.log('get value of "stats/attack"\n  return value ->'
           , onElm( data, 'stats/attack'  ) ) // return value -> 5

console.log('change value of "stats/attack to 10"\n  return value ->'
           ,  onElm( data, 'stats/attack', 10) ) // return value ->  10

console.log ( '\nverify data Object now with new value: \n', data  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Do have to be defensive with it could return undefined

Comment: Great, I need something like this, but to edit the "attack" field. for example if I want to change it to 10. I will test to see if I can do it with this method

Comment: your `wrong path` example has problems since it returns a string to the next iteration of the reduce. `stats/xxx/1` --> `r`. Better to just use optional chaining and return undefined as expected when a property isn't present `reduce((o,v) => o?.[v], obj)`

Comment: Of course it's also an 11 year old duplicate

Comment: @pilchard  I didn't see my third answer in the "duplicate link"... ?

Comment: You mean to set the value? It's included in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43849204/13762301)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash `zipObjectDeep` to achieve that but path works via '.', so you need to

```
const edit = 'stats/attack';
const path = edit.split('/').join('.')
zipObjectDeep([path], [1]);
```

[Lodash zipObjectDeep doc](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipObjectDeep)

Answer (score -1):

Replace all `/` with `.` then `eval` the string that represents `obj.this.that`.

Bonus: This works for arrays too `"stats/level[2]/other"`

```js
var obj = {
  "id_": "1",
  "name": "Enemy x",
  "image": "image.png",
  "stats": {
    "level": 1,
    "attack": 5,
    "defense": 0
  }
};

var path = "stats/level";
var value = (eval ("obj." + path.replace(/\//g, ".")));
console.log(value)
```